# dynamically update UL of MySQL rows

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, dynamic, vimeo

I have this little test site in the works:

http://s199881165.onlinehome.us/transfem/DBO3/

It is trying to be a video playlist player that grabs videos from the VIMEO API using the number at the end of their Urls (such as vimeo.com/*7100569*)

It works using a list of those URLs stored in a MySQL table.

As of now, I have the ability to reset the list to a default list of 9 videos.
I can re-order the videos using jquery sortable (drag the boxes), when this happens it updates the MySQL DB so that the next time you load the page the new order persists.

I can add a video to the end of the list and I can remove the last video from the list.

HOWEVER the `<UL>` and the loop of iframes that create the top buttons and the video player div respectively only get info from the DB at the initial page load and so if the database changes those lists on the page remain unchanged.

**My question is:**

How can I have those elements listen to updates in the MySQL database and then automatically adjust, re-arrange, delete, or whathaveyou.

I am looking at needing AJAX? jQUERY? JSON? And if so what is a game plan of things to try or learn in order to make this happen?

Best, Will

Answer (score 0):

You can't have them listen to updates but you might poll mysql and then update page if needed.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp
http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-use-jquery-settimeout-function.html